# MODULENAME_page_attachment_alter() Undefined

Tags: 8, hooks

I have a custom module named `rsm_library`.  I would like to use `hook_page_attachment_alter()` in `rsm_library.module` and called the hook as follows:

```
rsm_library_page_attachment_alter($attachments);
```

I then issued `$ drush cr` to clear the caches.

This resulted in:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Error: Call to undefined function
>   rsm_library_page_attachments_alter().

Comment: Also its not clear what you are doing - you cannot call the function without defining it, it will be automatically invoked for you when alter hooks are called from the main call. The function definition is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function rsm_library_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, adding this code to rsm_library.module gave me a solution. My hook is invoked and I can work with the $attachments array.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, there's a typo. It's not attachment, it's attachment**s**.

Next, you can't simply call a function without defining it.

In Drupal hooks are used to modify existing code when it's being processed.

See [`hook_page_attachments_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x) for an example of what you are supposed to do.

Using hooks, you simply define a new function prefixed with your module's machine name, put your code/alterations in there, and in the end it's automatically being *hooked up* for execution. No need to call it again.

> ```
> function hook_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
>
>   // Conditionally remove an asset.
>   if (in_array('core/jquery', $attachments['#attached']['library'])) {
>     $index = array_search('core/jquery', $attachments['#attached']['library']);
>     unset($attachments['#attached']['library'][$index]);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: If you look at the 8.2 version of hook_page_attachments_alter (which is the highest ranked in Google), there is not an example of how to use the hook. The 8.5 version has an example for the theme layer -- which would have likely been enough to understand how to use the hook.  Too bad.

Comment: @GregSims – I also blockquoted the example from that page. What you mean is a comment.